# How can I make a db process scalable?

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, function, scalability

My application get **[AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vehicle_location)** data from different sources and merge it in a pool table.

Then I have a function `map.get_near_link(sq.X, sq.Y, sq.AZIMUTH)` to calculate what is the closest link to every car position in that pool.

```
CREATE TYPE map.get_near_link AS
   (link_id integer,
    distance integer,  -- distance to the link
    sentido integer,   -- use azimuth to know what direction of link is traveling
    geom geometry(4)); -- the link geometry
```

Currently I receive around ~400 avl for minute, and the process of calculate `near_link` for all those takes between 10-30 sec. So in theory I can process all the records without any problem. But if source input increase to +800 avl/ min, I wont be able to process all the data.

So what measure should I take so my process handle a future increase in the  size of data input.

**This is my current process.** I set a job to run every min.

```
-- new records doesnt have near_link
SELECT MAX(avl_id) INTO int_pending 
FROM   avl_db.avl_pool
WHERE  near_link IS NULL;   

-- loop while the pool isnt empty
WHILE  int_pending > 0  LOOP  
    --udpate take around 10-30 sec   
    UPDATE avl_db.avl_pool a
    SET near_link = map.get_near_link(sq.X, sq.Y, sq.AZIMUTH)
    FROM ( 
         -- this select take ~100 ms
         SELECT avl_id, x, y, azimuth
         FROM avl_db.avl_pool
         WHERE near_link IS NULL
         ORDER BY avl_id
         LIMIT 400 -- I choose 400 after some testing, 
                   -- so doesnt lock the table for too long.
        ) sq
    WHERE a.avl_id = sq.avl_id;

    -- check if pool is empty
    SELECT MAX(avl_id) INTO int_pending 
    FROM   avl_db.avl_pool
    WHERE  near_link IS NULL;       
END LOOP;
```

**Just for reference:**

**avl_pool table**

```
CREATE TABLE avl_db.avl_pool
(
  avl_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  car_id bigint,
  hora timestamp without time zone,
  x numeric(10,6),
  y numeric(10,6),
  azimuth integer,
  speed numeric(10,3),
  near_link map.get_near_link,
  CONSTRAINT avl_pool_pkey PRIMARY KEY (avl_id)
);
```

This is the **`map.get_near_link`** function. I work a lot to try make it the more efficient possible, but if have to work again to reduce the time can accept suggestions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map.get_near_link(
    x numeric, y numeric, azim numeric)
  RETURNS map.get_near_link AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    strPoint text;
    sRow map.get_near_link;
  BEGIN
    strPoint = 'POINT('|| X || ' ' || Y || ')';

    with index_query as (
        SELECT Link_ID, azimuth, 
               TRUNC(ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText(strPoint,4326), geom  )*100000)::integer as distance, 
               sentido, geom
        FROM map.vzla_seg S
        WHERE 
            abs(Azim - S.azimuth) < 30 OR
            abs(Azim - S.azimuth) > 330
        ORDER BY 
            geom <-> ST_GeomFromText(strPoint, 4326)
        LIMIT 101
    )
    SELECT i.Link_ID, i.Distance, i.Sentido, v.geom into sRow 
    FROM 
        index_query i inner join 
        map.vzla_rto v ON i.link_id = v.link_id
    ORDER BY 
        distance limit 1;

    if sRow.distance > 50 then
        sRow.link_id = -1;
    end if;

    RETURN sRow;
  END;
```

Comment: (1) Please add DDL + cardinality of the tables (2) Can we assume that you've created spatial indexes and that they are being used by the optimizer? (3) Can we assume that there is a maximum relevant distance between the AVL and a link which is relative good filter?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz (1) avl_pool increase ~400 records/ min, I clean the pool table very often, so at max around 100k records. (2) Yes, there is spatial index, speed a lot the `<->` to find the near link. (3) Yes, I limit the search to the 100 link closest and then `if sRow.distance > 50 then` (4) I will add the ddl, but not much more already show. x, y, azimuth, near_link

Comment: What does `ST_GeomFromText()` do?  It is called twice and you have to compose a string for it.  Can you re-write it to take X and Y?

Comment: `abs(Azim - S.azimuth) NOT BETWEEN 30 AND 330` -- no idea if this would help -- depends on your platform.

Comment: @Hogan geom is a spatial type from postgis extension. That function take a geom_text and convert to geom object. I can create a `WITH parameter` to calculate once. But the heavy part is the `select ..order <->` Still I can found the `near_link` for 400 records in 30 sec when the map have 600k links doesnt look slow. Lets say I get down to 10 sec, Still I wont be able to scale to +1200 record/min. So I need do something else

Comment: In my experience when I've seen an SQL statement with two or more function calls the way to improve performance was to get rid of the function calls.  For me function calls are a bad smell in SQL.  You might consider finding a way to externally calculate these values and store them in the db.

Comment: (1)  I am more interested in the number of links. (3) I am talking about absolute distance. Would you direct the vehicle to a link in a distance of 10km? 100km? 1000km?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz sorry didnt got that one. Are around 600k links, And I only consider **near** if distance is less than 50 meters.  Is just to display where is the car at that moment.

Comment: And how many links can we expect in a radius of 150 feet?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Not sure, because depend if is inside the city or highways. But lets say max 1000 links inside city. But `<->` work great limit close result.

Comment: @Hogan The problem is `x, y` came from the gps. So I need to create the `point` geom object for each record and then calculate the distance with `line` objects already in the db.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- why is that a problem?  My question is "What is in the function?"  and my point is "If you can move that functionality inline you should do so."  Function overhead is large -- very large.  You should move it if you can.

Comment: @Hogan `ST_GeomFromText` is a postgis extension function. Not sure what is there.

Answer (score 0):

The where-clause with `abs(Azim - S.azimuth) < 30` cannot use any index on `S.azimuth`. Each SELECT will result in a full table scan.

If you calculated the valid azimuth range (or ranges) before performing the SELECT query, you could have a condition like `azimuth BETWEEN low AND high`. Together with an index on `azimuth` this would speed up the query.

Comment: I cant do that. If car is going azimuth 0. Road links with azimuth 345 and 15 are in the same direction. But I will check that condition again

Comment: As you can check [**HERE**](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Lr38) the `<->` use spatial index to find 100 object near, and then do the filter for azimuth. So is very efficient only need 30 ms.